# For Loop - Circle instead of Linear

Tags: for-loop, unity-game-engine, textures, geometry

I have an array of pixel data taken from a Texture2D (512 x 512) within Unity.

Currently, I'm adding a border around this texture by using a for loop and setting the outer pixels to Color.black.

But some Texture2Ds are actually circular (in terms of the image/photo itself). And I would like to add a circular border around these images.

The typical for-loops (r++ & c++) gives a linear (bottom left, to top right) value, which wont work for a circle, right? Is there some kind of algorithm I can use to make the for-loop circular (in terms of the r and c values)?

Does this make any sense?

Thanks.

Comment: no, i dont think it does.

Comment: There's no need to make the for loop iterate circularly (which, even if possible, is far from the simplest way to solve this problem). Just use the `r` and `c` values with an equation for a circle within the loop, and you can determine whether the coordinates lie in/out of a given circle. With that logic worked out, you can just colour the pixels that are outside of a slightly smaller circle, but inside a slightly larger one.

Answer (score 1):

*Funny question :)*

I can't think of a solution to make for-loop 'circular', becouse x and y depend on each other and simple x++ y++ is not possible.

A simple solution is to calculate x and y inside some loop. Like using `x = r*cos(t); y = r*sin(t);` and iterating over `t`

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8q23f1b3/2/), it draws circle on html canvas using `for-loop` :D

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want the end result to look like, you might be better off modifying via a shader to do a form of edge detection (it does depend on what you're texture is though).

Another, possibly easier solution is just to layer a second texture on top of your original where the second is just the border with the rest alpha'd out.